# feel disgusted vs feel disgusting

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

**disgusted** and **disgusting** are both verbs.
So what sort of specific situations are these two words used?

For example, in these two sentences,which sentence is correct?

> I feel **disgusted** in my mouth"

or

> i feel **disgusting** in my mouth"

Answer (score 2):

If you feel

> **disgusted**

it means you are feeling revulsion and profound disapproval about something

if your mouth feels

> **disgusting**

it means there's something about your mouth that people will be disgusted by

You would normally say

> My mouth feels **disgusting**.

Answer (score 0):

***Disgusted vs Disgusting:***

*Disgusted* is basically used for to dislike something means a strong distaste from surfeit. And it's synonyms are : sick of, tired of, and fed up.
While

*Disgusting* is talking about others behavior or charectistic means you are affecting from others  like: a disgusting smell, distasteful language, revolting food.

Now according top your questions like:
1. "I feel disgusted in my mouth", it means that you are feeling distasteful or fed up something.
2. "I feel disgusting in my mouth", it means that something from your mouth others will be revolting.